How do I rebuild my IntelliJ Codename One Maven Project?
I was looking at the external libraries of my Codename One app as I try to discover why my database cannot be successfully created and accessed, and I saw that my pom file has 46 errors. A few times as I have shut down IntelliJ I get a dialog that comes up that the Maven project id rebuilding. I have left my computer on over night in that state and the rebuild never finished. Does anyone have any idea on the steps to repair the pom and complete the Maven rebuild?

Can you share screenshots? I'm not sure what you would mean by "rebuilding"? What sort of errors?
